# Azure Function App is very slow, but only sometimes

Tags: azure, performance, azure-functions

I have read through most of the questions that seems to be similar to what I'll ask so hopefully I'm not wasting anyone's time.

We have a Function App in Azure Cloud that contains several Durable Functions.
One of these durable functions is a HTTP trigger API REST call.
It will normally take between 0.5 - 3 seconds to execute fully (from call to done, delivered result). But sometimes it takes 20-35 seconds. I don't know why or how I can search for errors.

The durable function fetches information from a Cosmos DB and delivers the result back to the caller.

Function App, Durable Function and Cosmos DB are all located in the same Region. (Checked that).
The Durable Function is set to B2:2 and has toggled Always On to ON.

Is there something I miss or something I should check to make sure it runs smoother?

Log of executions of the app:
[image: Execution Log with time]

I greatly appreciate everyone's time and energy they put into helping me. Thanks a lot.

---- Additions to the post after posting ----

I have checked the interactive tool and if I read that correctly it tells me a maximum execution time of 0.8 seconds and a maximum network lag of 6 seconds. That would indicate something that I suspected before I set up this post and that is that Azure needs to cold start the function. But I have always on toggled on so why?

It doesn't seem to take 30 seconds to complete the function. It seems to take less than 1 second to complete the function and up to a maximum of 6 seconds lag, but where are the other 23 seconds going in a 30 second call?

B2:2 is the service agreement I have with Azure. B2 is the test environments second paid state with 2 instances scaling (I have changed that to 3 after posting this).
Application Insights are on and no other dependencies are present except the Cosmos DB.

Comment: Have you checked the interactive tool : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-diagnostics ? It's a good one to start with.
If this is not relevant enough, we would need to look into the logs, networking architecture, code, etc. There are many possible reasons.

Comment: Do you mean an activity function takes 30s to complete?

Comment: I have a couple of questions... If it's 'just' a REST endpoint, why implement it in a durable function? With B2:2, do you mean the function app runs in an App Service? Do you have Application Insights available, and can you see dependencies? Is the function app under a lot of load when it's slow? Is the Cosmos DB database?

Comment: No I had not checked the interactive tool, but now I have and this confirms a thought I had prior to setting up this question that page claims that the execution time is way  WAY lower with a peak at 6 seconds lag and 0.8 seconds execution time.

Comment: Yes it takes, sometimes over 30 seconds.

Comment: I cannot answer why it's a durable function, it's set up like that by me predecessor. Yes B2:2 is the Function App's App Service Plan. Yes I have Application Insights, there are no dependencies apart from Cosmos DB. No it doesn't seems to be under heavy load which seems to be confirmed by the interactive tool. Yes Cosmos DB is the database we store documents related to the service in.

Comment: Is anything else running on the B2 App Service Plan? When looking at the App Service Plan metrics, is CPU, Memory, thread count, or SNAT ports exhausted when you see the slowdown? Are there downstream spikes in your databases that could leave threads in your function waiting? Have you considered deploying to an EPx instance (Premium Function) that just has this function, and see if that solves your issues?

Comment: you can enable the cosmos query metrics on the driver to better check the time consumed by it and where, app insights gives good info in the performance tab

Answer (score 3):

**AFAIK in Azure Functions**,

- After 5 minutes of inactivity, Function App goes to the cold state. To come out of it, 10 seconds delay occurs.
- Even the Function App is in Hot State, it will take some excessive amount of time to load the external libraries defined in it.
- In the Function App, Code Logic Performance also matters the cause of slowness in the Azure Functions.

**There are few steps for reducing the cold-start times particularly for the Functions having external libraries:**

- Running from a package file **`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`** to `1` may reduce cold-start times, particularly for JavaScript functions with large `npm` package trees.
- From the Azure Portal > **`Diagnose and solve problems`** > Troubleshoot Performance category to identify the causes of slowness:

[image]

[image]

- Try **`Always On`** Feature available in **App Service Plan** and **Premium Plan** of the Azure Functions to prevent such issues.
- Regarding the Performance and reliability improving of Azure Functions, please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/performance-reliability).

If this issue persists still, then please raise an incident with Microsoft Support to get the root cause and resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling around with `maxqueuepollingintervall`. It helped out with our cold starts quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that too. We have done a work around at the moment where we don't use these in the same way anymore, but it's still interesting to know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).